# str_detect in dplyr filter with character variable

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data frame like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(5),
                 v2 = c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'ee'))
```

I want to filter the rows where `v2` == 'aa'. This is easy with dplyr and `str_detect` from the stringr package

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(v2, 'aa'))
```

However, I am having trouble integrating this into a workflow where the column name of `v2` changes.

so the column name is stored as a string and is parsed to filter, but it doesn't work:

```
var <- 'v2'
df %>% filter(str_detect(var, 'aa'))
```

I tried combinations of `eval` and `parse` but it doesn't work either

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(parse(var), 'aa'))
df %>% filter(str_detect(eval(var), 'aa'))
df %>% filter(str_detect(eval(parse(var)), 'aa'))
```

Comment: You need `get` , `df %>% filter(str_detect(get(var), 'aa'))`. In fact, you were very close with `eval(parse(..`, You needed `df %>% filter(str_detect(eval(parse(text = var)), 'aa'))`